# Exclude Project in sln from dotnet build

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, msbuild

I have a roslyn analyzer project based on Microsoft's default template. I can easily build the analyzer in Visual Studio or with msbuild.

The problem is that the solution includes a vsix project that relies on the `microsoft.vssdk.buildtools` which are not supported by dotnet build.
This results in an error message when trying to build the solution in the command line with dotnet build: `microsoft.vssdk.buildtools\17.4.2119\tools\VSSDK\Microsoft.VsSDK.targets(826,5): error : VSIX deployment is not supported with 'dotnet build'`

The vsix is nice to have when developing with Visual Studio, but I do publish my analyzer via NuGet package instead of as vsix so I don't need the vsix on the CLI.

Is there a way to specify in the csproj that I don't want it to be built when it is invoked from dotnet build? I'd like to avoid having a separate sln file or a specific dotnet configuration that excludes the project if possible.

Comment: Build each project individually (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build#arguments)

Comment: @Jeremy That's even worse than simply having two sln files - that will also have a large performance impact because I no longer build it in parallel.

Comment: Well, that's what dotnet build supports. Either all the .sln / .*proj in the working directory, or a single named file.

Comment: Attempting `dotnet build [proj1] [proj2]` suggests that the `dotnet build` command does support parsing multiple project filenames. But fails when passing multiple projects to `msbuild`.

Comment: Try a [solution filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/filtered-solutions?view=vs-2022), then try to use this `dotnet build my-solution.slnf`. Not sure if that works, or is supported with `dotnet build`. Other than that, why do you think building in parallel is not supported, when you build the projects individually?

Comment: @Christian.K How would you pass multiple projects to dotnet build at one time? And if you concurrently call dotnet build A, dotnet build B (cumbersome but doable sure), you'll run into problems with transitive dependencies. A slnf seems like a good solution to avoid duplications though, hadn't thought of that.

Comment: I would use a wrapper MSBuild file and run that. (e.g. build.proj: `<Project ...><ItemGroup><Projects Include="**\*.csproj" Exclude="<whatyoudonotwant>.csproj"></ItemGroup> <Target Name="Build"> <MSBuild Projects="@(Projects)" .../> </Target></Project>`. `dotnet build build.proj`). Not 100% sure if that works though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible approaches include using a solution filter and changing the project to not build under certain conditions.

### Use a Solution Filter

`dotnet build` will accept a solution filter file (.slnf).

To create the solution filter:

1. Open the solution in Visual Studio
2. Go to the solution explorer window
3. Right-click on the VSIX project, choose 'Unload Project'
4. Right-click on the solution, choose 'Save As Solution Filter'

When building with dotnet the .slnf will need to be used. Using the .sln file or the VSIX project file with dotnet will be an error.

### Detecting when Invoked from dotnet build

There isn't a defined property or function in MSBuild that identifies the executable that is running the MSBuild engine.

However there is a `MSBuildRuntimeType` property.

Prior to MSBuild 15, `MSBuildRuntimeType` will be undefined. In MSBuild 15 and later `MSBuildRuntimeType` will have a value of `Full`, `Core`, or `Mono`. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties?view=vs-2022) `MSBuildRuntimeType` will have a value of `Core` when `dotnet build` is used. (Further the error message "VSIX deployment is not supported with 'dotnet build'" is only displayed when `'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)' == 'Core'`.)

There isn't an 'exit build' task so the project can't detect and then end. We need to detect before the project really starts. But wrapping a project within a project is clunky especially if you want to be able to work with the project and change properties from the Visual Studio IDE.

Targets can be redefined and an [`Import`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/import-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022) can have a condition. A file can be imported when `MSBuildRuntimeType` is `Core` and the file can redefine the 'Build' target.

Add to the VSIX project file:

```xml
    <Import Project="noop.targets" Condition="'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)' == 'Core'" />
```

The noop.targets may contain the following:

```xml
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="Build">
        <Message Text="$(MSBuildProjectName) has been skipped." />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Hope this helps or at least provides some ideas.

Comment: My original thinking was whether some "stop this build" property existed, but overwriting the build action is a clever workaround. I wasn't thinking of solution filters, but they have the downside of having to be kept in sync with the sln file so this is nicer.

Comment: The .slnf contains a relative path to the .sln that it is 'filtering' and the IDE will help with keeping the files in sync. But yes some action is needed.

Comment: What I meant with "in sync" is that I have to add every new project to the sln and the slnf - a small problem (not like we're adding the projects every day) but it's a minor flaw so I like the target redirection.

Comment: You don't need to manually edit the solution filter file. Steps for adding a new project to the .slnf consist of opening the .slnf file in Visual Studio, right-clicking on the solution icon in the solution explorer window and choosing 'show unloaded projects' (which will show all the projects in the .sln), right-clicking on the new project and choosing 'reload project', and when VS prompts saving the updated .slnf file.

Comment: I'm on a non-windows platform.  Is there a way to create a solution filter without VS?

Comment: I'm only aware of VStudio for creating solution filter files. Not having a non-windows way to generate a filter is a hole that should be filled. But the .slnf is a JSON file and ["Solution filters in MSBuild"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/solution-filters?view=vs-2022) shows some examples. As a one-off, it shouldn't be too difficult to create a filter file by hand.

Comment: JetBrains Rider will create a solution filter file - see ["Work with solution filters"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Solution_filters.html)